# Segmentation fault: Address not mapped / Failing at address: (nil)

Tags: c++, openmpi, avx

I am using Tensorflow's C API to do inference within a parallelized simulation. As I wanted AVX support I compiled Tensorflow from source. I linked it and compiled everything using wmake.

Now if I start a normal (non-parallelized) simulation run, everything works fine. But if I parallelize it I get this error immediately after starting the simulation run:

```
[node134:18796] *** Process received signal ***
[node134:18796] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[node134:18796] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[node134:18796] Failing at address: (nil)
[node134:18796] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x3ef20)[0x7fec1c96ff20]
[node134:18796] [ 1] /home/elias/OpenFOAM/elias-4.1/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib/libtensorflow_framework.so(hwloc_bitmap_and+0x14)[0x7fec01c21534]
[node134:18796] [ 2] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopen-pal.so.20(opal_hwloc_base_filter_cpus+0x380)[0x7febe59d6b80]
[node134:18796] [ 3] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_ess_pmi.so(+0x2b4e)[0x7febe4902b4e]
[node134:18796] [ 4] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopen-rte.so.20(orte_init+0x22e)[0x7febe5c2a1de]
[node134:18796] [ 5] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.20(ompi_mpi_init+0x30e)[0x7febffdbc27e]
[node134:18796] [ 6] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.20(MPI_Init+0x6b)[0x7febffddd2ab]
[node134:18796] [ 7] /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib/openmpi-system/libPstream.so(_ZN4Foam8UPstream4initERiRPPc+0x1f)[0x7fec1c72843f]
[node134:18796] [ 8] /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib/libOpenFOAM.so(_ZN4Foam7argListC1ERiRPPcbbb+0x719)[0x7fec1db36ed9]
[node134:18796] [ 9] tabulatedCombustionFoam(+0x279b8)[0x55fe6eb489b8]
[node134:18796] [10] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7)[0x7fec1c952b97]
[node134:18796] [11] tabulatedCombustionFoam(+0x30a0a)[0x55fe6eb51a0a]
[node134:18796] *** End of error message ***
```

I tried to fix it on my own but so far I do not see any progress. Can somebody recognize the reason for this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I did not assume that the code might be wrong, as it worked under following conditions:
- without parallelization
- in parallel with Standard C API Version one can download

Here is the relevant part of the "main":

```
if(InferenceMode==0)
            {
                auto t_start_0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
                const char* frozenGraphName = "/home/elias/Lr75-57_FPVANN_premix/data/FPV_ANN_tabulated_Standard_500.pb";

                const std::string iON = string(input_layer_name);
                const char* inputOperationName = iON.c_str();
                const std::string oON = string(output_layer_name) + "/BiasAdd";
                const char* outputOperationName = oON.c_str();

                int no_of_inputs = in_mean.size();
                int no_of_outputs = out_mean.size();
                int cellsAndPatches = (input_f_zeta_PVNorm.size())/no_of_inputs;
                std::vector<int64_t> input_dimensions = {cellsAndPatches,no_of_inputs};
                std::vector<int64_t> output_dimensions = {cellsAndPatches,no_of_outputs};

                Inference* inf = new Inference();
                bool success = inf->doInference(frozenGraphName,inputOperationName,outputOperationName,no_of_inputs,no_of_outputs,input_dimensions,output_dimensions,cellsAndPatches,input_f_zeta_PVNorm,output_real,limit_cores);
                delete inf;

                auto t_end_0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
                auto total_0 = std::chrono::duration<float, std::milli>(t_end_0 - t_start_0).count();
                std::cout << "TOTAL INFERENCE TIME C API: " << total_0 << std::endl;
            }
```

This is the header file:

```
#ifndef INFERENCEC_H
#define INFERENCEC_H

#include "c_api.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <memory>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <thread>

static void DeallocateBuffer(void* data, size_t)
{
    std::free(data);
}

static TF_Buffer* ReadBufferFromFile(const char* file)
{
    const auto f = std::fopen(file, "rb");
    if (f == nullptr)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    std::fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    const auto fsize = ftell(f);
    std::fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

    if (fsize < 1)
    {
        std::fclose(f);
        return nullptr;
    }

    const auto data = std::malloc(fsize);
    std::fread(data, fsize, 1, f);
    std::fclose(f);

    TF_Buffer* buf = TF_NewBuffer();
    buf->data = data;
    buf->length = fsize;
    buf->data_deallocator = DeallocateBuffer;

    return buf;
}

static void DeallocateTensor(void* data, std::size_t, void*) // vorher void* arg
{
    std::free(data);
}


class Inference
{
public:
    bool doInference(const char*,const char*,const char*,int,int,std::vector<int64_t>,std::vector<int64_t>,int,std::vector<float>&,std::vector<float>&,int);
};

#endif // INFERENCEC_H
```

This is the .C file:

```
#include "inferenceC.H"

bool Inference::doInference(const char* fgn, const char* iname, const char* oname, int nIn, int nOut, std::vector<int64_t> dimIn,std::vector<int64_t> dimOut, int CP, std::vector<float> &inVals, std::vector<float> &outVals, int maxCores)
{   
    TF_Buffer* graph_def = ReadBufferFromFile(fgn);

    if (graph_def == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "Can't read buffer from file" << std::endl;
    }

    TF_Graph* graph = TF_NewGraph();
    TF_Status* status = TF_NewStatus();
    TF_ImportGraphDefOptions* graph_opts = TF_NewImportGraphDefOptions();

    TF_GraphImportGraphDef(graph, graph_def, graph_opts, status);

    if(TF_GetCode(status)!=TF_OK)   
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR: Unable to import graph " << TF_Message(status) << std::endl;
    }

    //int num_bytes_in = CP*nIn*sizeof(float);
    //int num_bytes_out = CP*nOut*sizeof(float);

    TF_DeleteImportGraphDefOptions(graph_opts);


    TF_DeleteBuffer(graph_def);


    assert((inVals.size()%nIn)==0);
    std::cout << "Effective batch size: " << (inVals.size()/nIn) << std::endl;

    TF_Output input = {TF_GraphOperationByName(graph, iname), 0};
    TF_Output output = {TF_GraphOperationByName(graph, oname), 0};

    const std::vector<std::int64_t> dims = {CP,nIn};
    std::size_t data_size = sizeof(float);
    for (auto i : dims)
    {
        data_size *= i;
    }

    auto data = static_cast<float*>(std::malloc(data_size));
    std::copy(inVals.begin(), inVals.end(), data);
    TF_Tensor* input_value = TF_NewTensor(TF_FLOAT,dims.data(), static_cast<int>(dims.size()),data, data_size,DeallocateTensor, nullptr);

    const std::vector<int64_t> outdims = {CP,nOut};
    std::size_t outdata_size = sizeof(float);
    for (auto i : outdims)
    {
        outdata_size *= i;
    }

    TF_Tensor* output_value = nullptr;

    std::cout << "Running session..." << std::endl;
    TF_SessionOptions* sess_opts = TF_NewSessionOptions();

    if(maxCores!=0)
    {        
        uint8_t intra_op_parallelism_threads = maxCores; // for operations that can be parallelized internally, such as matrix multiplication 
        uint8_t inter_op_parallelism_threads = maxCores; // for operationss that are independent in your TensorFlow graph because there is no directed path between them in the dataflow graph
        uint8_t config[]={0x10,intra_op_parallelism_threads,0x28,inter_op_parallelism_threads};
        TF_SetConfig(sess_opts,config,sizeof(config),status);
        if (TF_GetCode(status) != TF_OK)
        {
            printf("ERROR: %s\n", TF_Message(status));
        }
    }


    TF_Session* session = TF_NewSession(graph, sess_opts, status);
    assert(TF_GetCode(status)==TF_OK);
    auto t_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    TF_SessionRun(session, nullptr, &input, &input_value, 1, &output, &output_value, 1, nullptr, 0, nullptr, status);

    auto t_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto total = std::chrono::duration<float, std::milli>(t_end - t_start).count();
    std::cout << "time required for TF_SessionRun: " << total << std::endl;

    float* out_vals = static_cast<float*>(TF_TensorData(output_value));

    std::vector<float> results(nOut*CP,0);
    for(int i=0;i<CP;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<nOut;j++)
        {
            results.at(i*nOut+j) = *out_vals;
            out_vals++;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Successfully ran session!" << std::endl;

    outVals = results;

    TF_CloseSession(session,status);
    TF_DeleteSession(session,status);
    TF_DeleteSessionOptions(sess_opts);
    TF_DeleteStatus(status);
    TF_DeleteGraph(graph);

    TF_DeleteTensor(output_value);
    TF_DeleteTensor(input_value);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Reduce your code to a [mcve] (i.e., remove everything not necessary to reproduce the behavior) -- ideally have only a single file left which contains `main` and all necessary `#include`s.

Comment: I will try. Do you at all think it is a code error at not some other problem? Bc. the same code worked with the old Tensorflow version without AVX without problem, moreover the application crashes before it reaches my own code...

Comment: You provided way too much code to see at a glance what causes your crash. The issue could well be due to ABI problems caused by incompatible compilation options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the following link shows it was no code error, instead there was a Tensorflow problem which is resolved on the current master branch:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/29838